# Checking multiple conditions in If statement in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I am new to Crystal reports.
In programming (Ex. in c), I can check two conditions in one single if statement.
ex. `if(A && B)`
How this can be done in Crystal Reporting?

Answer (score 4):

you need to put AND instead of && to achieve this in CR. Like this

```
if (something >=5) AND (something <10) then
something
```